# How display block that overwflows table cell?

Tags: apache, cell, tablelayout, apache-fop

I render a table using Apache™ FOP (Formatting Objects Processor). I want to display a yellow block with fixed height and width. Block bottom should be at the same position where row bottom is. Block should overflow cells, block should not make cell larger. I'd rather not use rowspan. Any idea how I can make block overflow cell in FOP?

Image with actual and expected output:

[image: output]

Approach 1: I tried already to rowspan=2. Table looks like expected. But the code is too complex. It requires extra logic to calculate which rows I need to span.

Approach 2:

```
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell><fo:block>item4</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell display-align="after">
    <fo:block-container overflow="visible">
        <fo:block background-color="yellow" padding-top="1.5mm" padding-bottom="1.5mm">
            Thanks
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
</fo:table-cell>
```

I was hoping overflow="visible" will do the trick, but it did not.

Comment: It would be better if you add some details on what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(preventive disclosure: I'm a FOP developer, albeit not very active nowadays)*

I think your approach #1 (i.e. using `number-rows-spanned`) is the **correct** one, as it provides the most portable solution across different formatters.

Anyway, if you want to go with a "simpler" trick you could use a negative `space-before` in the special yellow blocks:

```
<fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
    <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
    <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid #000000"><fo:block>orange 1</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid #000000"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid #000000"><fo:block>orange 2</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid #000000"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid #000000"><fo:block>orange 3</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid #000000">
                <fo:block space-before="-12.8pt" space-before.conditionality="retain" background-color="yellow" padding-top="4pt" padding-bottom="4pt" font-size="16pt">Thanks</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

- the negative `space-before` must be the difference between the height of a *normal* block and the height of the *special* one (it's easier if all lengths are expressed in points, as I did in the example): in this case (12 * 1.2) - (16 * 1.2 + 4 + 4) = -12.8
- `space-before.conditionality="retain"` is needed to avoid the space to be discarded (as it is at the beginning of a cell)
- this dirty trick only works correctly if both the *normal* and the *special* blocks produce a single line of text
- tested with FOP 1.1 and FOP trunk

In conclusion you *may* be able to avoid using row-spanning cells, but it is not going to be much simpler, and it is surely a less general solution.

Comment: lfurini space-before="-12.8pt" and space-before.conditionality="retain" does the trick. But I wonder why I cannot simply (without tricks) align the block to the bottom of the cell. Why I cannot put  2in x 2in block into 1in x 1in cell and let the block take other cell spaces?

Comment: @JasWodnik, the general behaviour is that the content of a cell affects the height of that cell and of the whole row (otherwise it would be extermely difficult to define tables); your use case is quite uncommon and can be dealt with more easily using spanning cells (which is the solution i would recommend).